# How to update TListview after adding record to TFDTable?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

A listview is bound to `BindSourceDB` with a `TFDTable` as dataset.
The listview does show the data from the dataset as expected.
However, when adding a new record to the dataset the binding does not automatically refresh the table: so the new record is not visible in the listview.

The record is added as follows:

```
DM.tbl_ExamQuestions.AppendRecord([
  0,
  StrToInt( ExamID ),
  DM.FDQuery.FieldByName('question_id').AsInteger,
  '-'
]);
```

Using `TBindings.Notify( BindSourceDB, '')` does not trigger the refresh.

Using `TBindNavigator` to add a record does repopulate the list.

How can I have the listview update itself in order to show the newly added record?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
DM.FDQuery.UpdateTransaction;

Comment: How does this update the ListView?  And from what, exactly?